# Why doesn't gcc 13 display the correct binary represenation?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-bug, pointer-conversion, c23

While answering a question here, I made the following example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) 
{
  float_t a = -248.75;
  printf("%f\n", a);

  unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)&a;
  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(a); i++)
  {
    printf("%.2X ", ptr[i]);
  }
}
```

On gcc before version 13 as well as all versions of clang, this gives the expected output (x86 little endian):

```
-248.750000
00 C0 78 C3
```

However, when compiling with gcc 13.1, I get nonsense output:

```
-248.750000
00 00 00 00
```

Further examination shows that the culprit is the option `-std=c2x`. If I remove it, the program behaves as expected.

Compiler options used: `-std=c2x -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -O3 -lm`. https://godbolt.org/z/4qbo74eEW

Is this a known bug in gcc?

Comment: Bonus points if someone can with some confidence say which is the latest stable version of gcc that can actually be safely used...

Comment: FWIW, adding the `-fno-strict-aliasing` command-line option results in GCC 13.1 and 13.2 emitting the correct result.  The optimizers have apparently run amok.

Comment: The same incorrect result is generated when `#include <math.h>` is removed and `float a = -248.75;` is used instead of `float_t a = -248.75;`

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. What happens is that no copy of `a` is put in the frame (which is needed because the address of `a` is taken). Thus the loop reads garbage.  Tested with avr-gcc version 13.2.1 20231018 (future v13.3). The same bug occurs with current master (future v14).

Comment: @Lundin Does replacing `unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)&a;` with `unsigned char  ptr[sizeof a]; memcpy(ptr, &a, sizeof a);` work for you?

Comment: To exercise FP related issues, 1) Does `float_t a = -248.75f;` (`f` added) change output? 2) What is the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`?

Comment: Notes: aliasing with `char` or `signed char` produces the expected result (w/ `%.2hhX`). Or using `volatile` to attack the optimizations. Or `printf("%f %p\n", a, (void *) &a);` to force the object to actually exist on the stack (and be initialized). Or `-std=c2x -O1`, as previously mentioned by Andrew, with `-O2` and up enabling `-fstrict-aliasing` - `-fno-strict-aliasing` generates the correct result. But `-std=c2x -Wall -fstrict-aliasing` also produces the correct result (but with [baffling diagnostics](https://godbolt.org/z/Gbrrsxs6z) not present with clang, gcc 12, `char`, or `-std=c11`).

Comment: @AndrewHenle But strict aliasing doesn't apply here. It has always been a never-ending source of bugs in gcc though...

Comment: @Lundin Some GCC devs apparently don't agree with that.  Perhaps someone pushing to apply strict aliasing to `uint8_t` went too far?  See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66110 for a bug report from a few years ago pushing for exactly that.  It wouldn't surprise me for GCC to do that - and break a whole lot of code based on decades-old implementation details assuming `uint8_t` pointers were `char` types and could alias, and then whine, "B-b-b-but the C standard doesn't say we can't do that!"

Comment: @AndrewHenle That whole thread is ridiculous. Just use`uint_fast8_t`, that's why it's there. There's a whole lot of code written assuming that `uint8_t` is a character type. Maybe those so-called "devs" should start their own "ISO Compliant Death Station" project and let gcc remain with at least a few weak ambitions to be a quality implementation, to be used in the real world where computer programs are written... This is one of many problems with open source - there's no commercial angle, so there's nobody pushing to make a quality product that people will actually use/buy.

Comment: Another example of gcc 13.2 going completely ape**** https://godbolt.org/z/16Wj5fj5v. May or may not be the same bug. gcc trunk fixes the problem. But to anyone reading this: stay far away from gcc 13.0 -> 13.2.

Comment: @Lundin "Just use `uint_fast8_t`, that's why it's there." Wouldn't `uint_least8_t` be better? `sizeof(uint_fast8_t)` could be greater than 1.

Comment: @Lundin Does gcc 13.2 go "completely ape****" with any dialect options other than `-std=c2x` or `-std=gnu2x`? Bear in mind that gcc's C2x support is still experimental and incomplete, so bugs are to be expected.

Comment: @IanAbbott They shouldn't make an official release before testing things properly. gcc was nowhere near this buggy ten years back, it's some sort of generation shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now filed as a GCC bug, cf. https://gcc.gnu.org/PR111884

v11 and v12 seem to work for me.

**Edit**: This bug is fixed now in v13.3+

Comment: I'd report it myself but I always check here first in case I'm mistaken.