# How do initial members, common initial sequences, anonymous unions, and strict aliasing interact in C?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, unions, strict-aliasing

So there are several things that are clearly allowed under the strict aliasing rules (for clarity, lets do this in C23):

The first and most obvious is that structs are allowed to alias with pointers to their initial members:

```c
typedef struct {
  int data;
} parent;

typedef struct {
  parent _base;
  int metadata;
} child;

int main() {
  child child_obj = {};
  parent* parent_ptr = (parent*) &child_obj; // Fine to read and write
  int* int_ptr = (int*) parent_ptr; // Also fine
}
```

The second is that unions of objects with common initial sequences allow access with those common elements, and a pointer to a union is freely convertible to/accessible as a pointer to any of its elements.

```c
typedef struct {
  int type_id;
  size_t size;
  char* buffer;
} dynamic_string;

typedef struct {
  int type_id;
  size_t number;
} just_a_number;

typedef union {
  dynamic_string dystr;
  just_a_number num;
  struct {
    int type_id;
    char fixed_string[32];
  };
} string_or_num;

int main() {
  string_or_num obj = {};

  if(obj.type_id == 2) // Fine, common initial sequence
    memcpy("Hello World!", obj.fixed_string, 13);

  // Fine
  dynamic_string* ds_ptr = (dynamic_string*) &obj;
  just_a_number* num_ptr = (just_a_number*) &obj;

  // Also fine, pointer to initial common member
  int* int_ptr = (int*) &obj;
}
```

Intuitively, I think I can combine these into something like the following. However, I'm not confident enough in my standardese to say with 100% certainty it is kosher

```c
typedef struct {
  int type_id;
  char data[4];
} parent_a;

typedef struct {
  int type_id;
  float decimal;
} parent_b;

// No initial sequence
typedef struct {
  double ccccombo_breaker;
} parent_c;

typedef struct {
  union {
    parent_a _base_a;
    parent_b _base_b;
    parent_c _base_c;
  };
  int look_at_me_ive_got_three_parents;
} child;

int main() {
  child child_obj = {};

  // Are these kosher?
  parent_a* a_ptr = (parent_a*) &child_obj;
  parent_b* b_ptr = (parent_b*) &child_obj;

  // How about this?
  parent_c* c_ptr = (parent_c*) &child_obj;
  double* db_ptr = (double*) &child_obj;
}
```

To be clear I'm not asking if something like `parent_c` is a good idea, just what the standard says about it. Would reads and writes through these pointers be following the aliasing rules?

Bonus points if you have exact language from the standard or a combination of standard sections that make a compelling case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are separate but mostly compatible rules:

- Pointer to first member of struct/any member of union (6.7.2.1 §15 §16), particularly:

  > The size of a `union` is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. The value of at
  > most one of the members can be stored in a `union` object at any time. A pointer to a
  > `union` object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bitfield,
  > then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
- Inspect byte by byte of any type using pointer to character (6.3.2.3 §7)
- "Strict aliasing" (chapter 6.5 §6 and §7)
- Common initial sequence (6.5.2.3)

Additionally, there's the rule about "union type punning" (6.5.2.3 §3) which allows a member of a union to be converted/expressed as a different type, although this may invoke all manner of poorly-defined behavior in case of misalignment, out of range values, invalid/trap representations and so on.

Your question is mainly about the first of these rules:

```
parent_a* a_ptr = (parent_a*) &child_obj;
parent_b* b_ptr = (parent_b*) &child_obj;
parent_c* c_ptr = (parent_c*) &child_obj;
```

These are fine as per that "any member of union" rule. An anonymous struct/union means that any of `_base_a`, `_base_b` and `_base_c` is "any member of a union" and therefore the pointer type is "suitably converted" by the cast. That these types happen to have a common initial sequence further down isn't really relevant. We can have a union of wildly incompatible types. Potential problems can only arise when accessing the actual data through a potentially non-compatible type or a type which is not an alias.

`double* db_ptr = (double*) &child_obj;` is however a bit questionable since the first object of `child_obj` is not a `double`. The pointer conversion itself is almost always fine, C allows pretty much any crazy conversion between object pointers (6.3.2.3 §7).

But if you de-reference `db_ptr` later, then you are on more questionable territory - the "pointer to any member of union" rule doesn't apply so it becomes a question of strict aliasing. Which in turn doesn't object of doing a `double` lvalue access to something that is potentially a `double`. And if the binary contents stored there (all zeroes) can also be represented as a `double`, then everything is in theory fine.

Notably, the history of real-world compiler implementations of these rules isn't very pretty (particularly not strict aliasing and common initial sequence). Lots of things are left unclear by the standard and it is better not to rely on whatever the standard says/seems to say, because that's not necessarily how one particular compiler interprets it. Plus some compilers do not even have the ambition to become a quality implementation. It is best practice not to trust the compiler to get any of this right. For example, the latest [gcc 13.2 goes completely bananas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77324211/why-doesnt-gcc-13-display-the-correct-binary-represenation) when facing the mentioned "inspect byte by byte" rule which has been in C since at least C99.

Comment: This mostly aligns with what I thought. I recognize the problems with type punning through unions. The nature of my question is really something along the lines of: Are the rules in the standard that discuss compatible pointers associative? Can I "compatible pointer" my way through several of the rules in sequence?

And the answer seems to be yes, with the usual caveats that compilers are not themselves the standard.

Answer (score -2):

Prior to C99, going back all the way to C74, if a pointer to a structure was converted into a pointer to another structure type sharing a common initial sequence, members of that common initial sequence could be inspected using the latter pointer just as well as the original.  On almost all implementations, writing as well as reading would be possible, the only potential issue being that a compiler for a little-endian platform where e.g. 32-bit word stores were faster than 16-bit stores might process something like:

```
struct foo {int x; short y; } *it; Assume int is 32 bits; short is 16 bits
...
it->y = 123;
```

with an instruction that would overwrite the 16 bits following `it->x`, which could overwrite a member of a structure like:

```
struct bar {int x; short y,z; } it2; Assume int is 32 bits; short is 16 bits
```

Some compiler writers informed the C99 Committee that it would sometimes be useful if a compiler given code that used e.g. position vectors, velocity vectors, and acceleration vectors didn't have to accommodate the possibility that operations which modified a `struct velocity_vector` might modify values stored in a `struct position_vector` or `struct acceleration_vector`.  Other members of the Committee recognized that this would fundamentally break the language.  As a compromise, the Committee decided to specify that programmers that relied upon the CIS guarantee being honored could declare a complete union type containing any structures that needed to be treated as sharing a common initial sequence, and compilers could deviate from the long-established CIS guarantees could do so either in situations that would be most useful to their customers, or whenever they felt like it if customer needs were not a concern.

Unfortunately, the Standard failed to make sufficiently clear that the phrase "anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible" includes all places where the completed type would be in scope according to ordinary rules of visibility, to prevent compiler writers from deciding to close their eyes to the existence of such definitions because it would "impede optimization" [never mind that the purpose was to ensure that compilers would produce correct results, rather than producing incorrect results "more efficiently"].

The net effect is that if one uses `-fno-strict-aliasing` flags with clang and gcc, they'll generally honor the letter and spirit of the Standard, and if one enables optimizations without applying that flag, they should not be relied upon to do so.

Comment: Sure but that doesn't answer the question, is _this_ a strict aliasing violation?

Comment: @nickelpro: Conversion of a union pointer into a pointer to any of its member's type is always permissible, if the storage is exclusively accessed using that same member type.  Conversion of a member pointer to a union containing that member is not permissible in the general case, and on clang may fail for reasons having to do with alignment rather than aliasing.  Given e.g. `struct foo {short x,y,z;}; union bar { int i; struct foo ptr; } *p1,*p2;`, clang may process `p1->ptr.x = p2->ptr.x; p1->ptr.y =p2->ptr.y;` using a single 32-bit read and write even on platforms that do not support...

Comment: ...unaligned access.  If `p1` and `p2` were known to satisfy the alignment requirements of all members in the union, that would be a useful optimization, but it will not support use cases where code might be passed a pointer to either a structure with 16-bit alignment or one structure with 32-bit alignment and want to access them through the union type in an effort to appease the free compiler gods.

Comment: This question isn't about alignment, it is only about the interaction with the strict aliasing rules, whether the compatible pointer rules regarding member objects of unions and first members of structs transitively apply. Whether the rules are such that when the first member of a struct is a union, that a pointer to any of the unions members is a valid access pointer for the child struct itself.

Comment: @nickelpro: My point was that casting a union pointer to a member pointer is guaranteed to work if only one member is *ever* accessed, but the reverse isn't guaranteed even if the only member that is ever accessed is of the original pointer's type.

Comment: The accepted answer and the standard disagree with you on the reverse not being guaranteed:  A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bitfield, then to the unit in which it resides), **and vice versa.**

Comment: @nickelpro: A pointer to a union member type may only be converted to the pointer-to-union type if it points to an actual union object.

Comment: As is the case in this question, so the answer to the question is "No this does not break strict aliasing"

Comment: @nickelpro: A simple "no" would cause readers to believe that other similar actions would be safe, even though clang or gcc would process them in surprising fashion.